# Extracting date time from HTTP response

Tags: python, datetime, http

When making a http get request i would like to extract the expiry date of an object.

my code below extracts the date time but gives me an error when trying to format the date/time to iso?

```
       #Extract date string from http response
        print("status: ", r.status_code)
        Expiry_Data = r.json()
        print(Expiry_Data)
        Expiry_Date = (Expiry_Data['response']['Expiry Date'])
        ExpiryDate = datetime.fromisoformat (Expiry_Date)
        print(ExpiryDate)
```

Please see an image of the error received.

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f37UY.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

datetime..strptime() may help you.

**Sample Code:**

```
from datetime import datetime

Expiry_Date = "2023-10-10T23:00:00.000Z"
ExpiryDate = datetime.strptime(Expiry_Date, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
print(ExpiryDate)
```

**Output:**

[image]